# Find nearest day of week for a given date and day of week

Tags: sql, date, t-sql

For a pair of dates `(date1, date2) = (Fri 2021-01-01, Wed 2020-01-01)` I need to extract the day of week from date1 (Friday in this case) then find the nearest Friday (or whatever) for date2.

The result for the above pair would be `Fri 2020-01-03` (2 days after that Wednesday) and not `Fri 2019-12-27` (5 days before that Wednesday).

There are examples that find previous/next day-of-week, use a hard-coded day of week or use `SET DATEFIRST` statement; all of which I must avoid. Here is some test data — pair of dates and expected result:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tests (
    date1 DATE,
    date2 DATE,
    result DATE
);

INSERT INTO #tests(date1, date2, result) VALUES
(/*Fri*/ '2021-01-01', /*Wed*/ '2020-01-01', /*Fri*/ '2020-01-03'),
(/*Sat*/ '2021-01-02', /*Thu*/ '2020-01-02', /*Sat*/ '2020-01-04'),
(/*Sun*/ '2021-01-03', /*Fri*/ '2020-01-03', /*Sun*/ '2020-01-05'),
(/*Mon*/ '2021-01-04', /*Sat*/ '2020-01-04', /*Mon*/ '2020-01-06'),
(/*Tue*/ '2021-01-05', /*Sun*/ '2020-01-05', /*Tue*/ '2020-01-07'),
(/*Wed*/ '2021-01-06', /*Mon*/ '2020-01-06', /*Wed*/ '2020-01-08'),
(/*Thu*/ '2021-01-07', /*Tue*/ '2020-01-07', /*Thu*/ '2020-01-09');

INSERT INTO #tests(date1, date2, result) VALUES
(/*Fri*/ '2021-01-01', /*Sun*/ '2017-01-01', /*Fri*/ '2016-12-30'),
(/*Sat*/ '2021-01-02', /*Mon*/ '2017-01-02', /*Sat*/ '2016-12-31'),
(/*Sun*/ '2021-01-03', /*Tue*/ '2017-01-03', /*Sun*/ '2017-01-01'),
(/*Mon*/ '2021-01-04', /*Wed*/ '2017-01-04', /*Mon*/ '2017-01-02'),
(/*Tue*/ '2021-01-05', /*Thu*/ '2017-01-05', /*Tue*/ '2017-01-03'),
(/*Wed*/ '2021-01-06', /*Fri*/ '2017-01-06', /*Wed*/ '2017-01-04'),
(/*Thu*/ '2021-01-07', /*Sat*/ '2017-01-07', /*Thu*/ '2017-01-05');
```

Comment: Do you have permissions/discretion to create a calendar dimension table that includes day of week data for spanning like 1900 to 2100? That would simplify the problem quite a bit.

Comment: @Error_2646 I have one and/or I can modify it.

Comment: Will the two dates inputs ever be the same day of the week - like both Wednesday? If so, should it return the next Wednesday or just the same second input date?

Comment: @error same date. Expect any date in inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can create/modify a calendar dimension, is this what you are after?

```
WITH
DAY_OF_WEEK_CALENDAR AS
  ( SELECT CAST('2021-04-01' AS DATE) AS date_id, 'Thursday' AS day_of_week UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-02' AS DATE), 'Friday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-03' AS DATE), 'Saturday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-04' AS DATE), 'Sunday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-05' AS DATE), 'Monday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-06' AS DATE), 'Tuesday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-07' AS DATE), 'Wednesday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-08' AS DATE), 'Thursday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-09' AS DATE), 'Friday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-10' AS DATE), 'Saturday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-11' AS DATE), 'Sunday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-12' AS DATE), 'Monday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-13' AS DATE), 'Tuesday' UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-14' AS DATE), 'Wednesday'
  ),
  TEST AS 
  ( SELECT CAST('2021-04-02' AS DATE) AS date_1,
           CAST('2021-04-10' AS DATE) AS date_2
      UNION
    SELECT CAST('2021-04-04' AS DATE) AS date_1,
           CAST('2021-04-10' AS DATE) AS date_2
  )
SELECT TEST.*,
       ( SELECT TOP 1 date_id
           FROM DAY_OF_WEEK_CALENDAR DOW_2
          WHERE DOW_2.date_id BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-7,TEST.date_2)
                   AND DATEADD(day,7,TEST.date_2)
            AND DOW_1.day_of_week = DOW_2.day_of_week
          ORDER
             BY DATEDIFF(day,DOW_2.date_id,TEST.date_2) ASC
       ) AS nearest_date_match
  FROM TEST
 INNER
  JOIN DAY_OF_WEEK_CALENDAR DOW_1
    ON TEST.date_1 = DOW_1.date_id
```

Comment: Top 1 and order by are not needed if you adjust the between clause just a little!

Comment: @SalmanA Interesting, how'd you get that working just by adjusting the between clause? I can't think of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it is very simple:

For `Wed 2020-01-01`, calculate -3 days and +3 days so you have a date range consisting of 7 days with Wednesday in the middle:

```
[Sun 2019-12-29 ... Wed 2020-01-01 ... Sat 2020-01-04]
```

This range contains all days of week nearest to the Wednesday; you just need to filter the desired day of week. This could be done via brute force (subquery), or by using a formula to further add/subtract some days. To find day of week based on another date the formula would be:

```sql
addto_date2_minus3days = (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date1) - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date2_minus3days) + 7) % 7
```

Query for the sample data in OP:

```sql
SELECT
    FORMAT(date1, 'ddd yyyy-MM-dd') AS date1,
    FORMAT(date2, 'ddd yyyy-MM-dd') AS date2,
    FORMAT(nearest_date, 'ddd yyyy-MM-dd') AS [nearest_dow(date1, date2)]
FROM #tests
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -3, date2) AS date2_minus3days
) AS ca1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date1) - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date2_minus3days) + 7) % 7, date2_minus3days) AS nearest_date
) AS ca2
```